# Btrfs subvolume @home not mounted kernel upgrade 3.17

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, btrfs

i'm having trouble upgrading my kernel to the latest 3.17 rc3 mainline kernel. 
I'm currently on a patched kernel 3.13 for my Acer chromebook c720p, the 3.17 kernel would give me support for touchpad and touch screen out-of-the-box.

When i boot the new kernel the btrfs @home subvolume is not found, i can boot without my home folder and use the guest account or tty2, but why is my home folder not recognised? And how can i mount it?

Need some help figuring this out, i'm new to working with btrfs. When i boot my 3.13 kernel again everything is fine again..
here are some config files..

fstab

```
UUID=42f4b88c-b4a7-45b5-b665-d74623bc351d /               btrfs   noatime,discard,ssd,autodefrag,compress=lzo,space_cache,subvol=@ 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=18d97557-fdbd-4359-b99f-7587f8c0add3 /boot           ext4    noatime,defaults            0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=42f4b88c-b4a7-45b5-b665-d74623bc351d /home           btrfs   noatime,discard,ssd,autodefrag,compress=lzo,recovery,clear_cache,subvol=@home 0       2
```

grub

```
recordfail
savedefault
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  18d97557-fdbd-4359-b99f-7587f8c0add3
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 18d97557-fdbd-4359-b99f-7587f8c0add3
fi
linux   /vmlinuz-3.17.0-031700rc3-generic root=UUID=42f4b88c-b4a7-45b5-b665-d74623bc351d ro rootflags=subvol=@  quiet splash elevator=noop intel_pstate=enable $vt_handoff
initrd  /initrd.img-3.17.0-031700rc3-generic
```

Comment: The mainline kernel is not supported - "The mainline kernels builds are produced for debugging purposes and therefore come with no support. Use them at your own risk." - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Mainline kernels, in the sense the upstream (kernel.org) project uses "mainline," are unstable. But [that article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) uses the term differently. Anyway, this site's policy about the *development release of Ubuntu* is just that: Ubuntu+1. If this post is in effect a bug report, we can of course close it and direct the OP to the appropriate bug tracker. But based on [a related but admittedly somewhat different consensus](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5576), it seems unlikely we would consider mainline kernel questions *inherently* off-topic.

Comment: I would respectfully disagree with that position. All of the ubuntu documentation clearly states custom kernels are not supported. Patching a kernel for a specific problem perhaps. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile. Nonetheless, as this site moderates by consensus ...

Answer (score 4):

Such behaviour is caused by a kernel bug introduced in 3.17-rc3, fixed in 3.17-rc6
(Revert "Btrfs: device_list_add() should not update list when mounted")